# C# CodeBehind Error When Using Webforms Front End

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to learn about generating an email with attachment(s) using C# CodeBehind. I would like the web page to use the FileUpload control or something similar to select the file on the network.

I get a "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Web Sites\myNet\Ztest\TrailerPics\'."

I'm wondering if I'm on the right path... or if there is a better approach.

Thx for any help ~j

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get file names from the fileUpload control
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        var fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
        var fileName3 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName);


        //Code block to send email with keyed data
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("DoNotReply@smiley.com");
            mail.To.Add("guy.smiley@sesamestreet.com");
            mail.Subject = ("IMG");
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var client = new SmtpClient("mailout.smiley.com", 25);
            string htmlBody;

            htmlBody = string.Format("Email Testing for attaching an image");

            mail.Body = htmlBody;

            //Create the instance of attachments by using the mapped path concatenated with the file name
            Attachment addon = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/TrailerPics/" + fileName));
            Attachment addon2 = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/TrailerPics/" + fileName2));
            Attachment addon3 = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/TrailerPics/" + fileName3));

            //Add the attachments as long as the fileUpload control has a file selected
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {                    
                mail.Attachments.Add(addon);                    
            }

            if (FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {                    
                mail.Attachments.Add(addon2);                    
            }

            if (FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {                   
                mail.Attachments.Add(addon3);                   
            }

            //Send mail
            client.Send(mail);

            //Notify that email was sent
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Email Sent!')", true);

            //Close all connections to the files 
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {
                addon.Dispose();
            }

            if (FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {
                addon2.Dispose();
            }

            if (FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {
                addon3.Dispose();
            }

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //inform user that the email failed
            errorLabel.Text = "Something went wrong with the email : " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are `fileName`, `fileName2`, and `fileName3`?

Comment: _I get a "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Web Sites\myNet\Ztest\TrailerPics\'."_ That doesn't look like a file name. Which line throws the error?

Comment: Amy... I'm using those to store the file name that was selected.  Debugging shows the correct file name

Comment: Sach according to debugger "Attachment addon = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/TrailerPics/" + fileName));" throws the error